# Why can't Iron Man travel to outer space?

Tags: iron-man

Why can't Iron Man travel to outer space with his suit on? What is the science behind that? Can't he use the material used to build the space shuttles to build his suit and travel into space?

Comment: Oxygen is a great deal for human beings.

Comment: It can be made possible, if Tony puts his mind to it. He built an arc reactor inside a cave, don't forget. He invented a new element from his own home lab. He created an AI. He created Ultron, and so on.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as from my perspective, it's unclear what you are asking. It isn't until *Avengers Assemble* that we see Tony attempt to go into space, and even then he survives thanks to one of his Iron Man suits. The question is based on a false premise.

Comment: Who says he can't? He's been in the ocean; that proves air-tight and oxygen- rich suit. I haven't seen him play Scrabble, that doesn't mean he can't do it. *False premise.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He actually can, just not with all of his suits (just as not all of them are supposed to be used underwater, in some vulcano, etc.).

As far as the *MCU* is concerned, **Iron Man 3** introduces the **Mark 39** (aka **Gemini** or **Starboost**), which [according to the Iron Man Wiki on Wikia](http://ironman.wikia.com/wiki/Mark_39):

> #### Extreme Flight
>
> The Mark 39 has the unique and special ability to fly at extremely high altitudes, and even reach into space. The armor is advanced enough to go out into the sub-orbit of Earth and the very vacuum of space itself.

And **Iron Man 3 - JARVIS: A Second Screen Experience**:

> **Sub-Orbital Suit** designed for off-earth missions. Armor features integrated removable **Booster Pack**, specialized **Maneuvering Thrusters**, and heavy gauge **Heat Shield**.

[image: Mark 39]

*From the [Image Gallery on Marvel.com](http://marvel.com/images/952386#0-952386)*

Answer (score 6):

He can travel into space, as shown in "Marvel's Avengers", via a portal.  However there's still going to be limits to how long he can be there, as also demonstrated.

The Iron-Man suit appears to be pressurised enough for him to survive the exposure to the vacuum of space, but the suit doesn't appear to have enough oxygen to support him in space.

This could be argued against from the scene where he's doing underwater welding in the suit, but that might extract oxygen from the water to sustain him.